# Did the discovery of zero affect our calendar and how we count days? Are we off by a tenth?

Tags: date, timeline

There have been a few articles written recently identifying the time at which the number zero was invented. Some stating the 9th century and recently a new carbon dating of a piece of parchment dates a symbol, that evolved into the zero, back the 3rd or 4th centuries.

If the zero didn't exist before these periods, then are we not off on our count by 10% (1/10) of actual days that existed previously and thus our modern year, inaccurate as well. It seems to me counting would have gone 1,2,3...8,9,11,12...18,19,21,22...

Comment: Please cit all references (a few articles, "some stating", etc.  ) It is really important to identify context & credibility of sources.  What has you research shown you so far? For example, a quick examination of [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) might address the second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but that's not my actual question... I want to know if we have correctly dated history considering the number 0 didn't exist, based on today's calendar, before year 0 AD. So did we account for that when calendars went through upgrades?

Comment: Thank you for you're comments, I completely blanked on roman numerology! Yes the citing was an issue, I should have used references so you could check, first time here sorry!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Don't apologize; with a little clarification of your question body I expect the down-votes will be retracted.

Comment: @Zensway How's the title now?

Comment: @Zensway I hope you realize now that you were imagining that ancient and medieval persons were really bad at counting and basic math, so that the lack of a numeral zero for creating the modern numeral "10" for ten meant that they had no numeral or concept of the number ten.

Answer (score 10):

Most folks are used to [positional numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) meaning they have a position to indicate the number of ones, the number of tens, the number of hundreds, and so on. The common [Hindu-Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) are positional. "102" is one hundred plus zero tens plus two ones.

You can see why a zero is necessary. Otherwise "12" could be "one hundred and two" or "ten and two (twelve)" or "one thousand and two tens".

Many prior number systems don't work that way. For example, [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) do the opposite. They use a different glyph for each magnitude, and repetition to indicate how many. "CII" is one hundred plus two ones.

There's no need for the numeral "zero". There's no ambiguity.

Similarly, [Greek numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals#Table) have specific numerals for 1 to 10, but also 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, and so on. 102 in ancient Greek 102 is ΡΒ or rho beta. 100 + 2.

Still others, such as [Chinese counting rods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_rods), were positional but had clear positions laid out on a grid or mat. 102 would be written as `|  ||`  with the space indicating an empty place. (*You might be surprised to know that [spaces to divide words are also a fairly recent invention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_divider). Reading was hard back then.*) Later various glyphs were used such as the [Zetian 〇](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters_of_Empress_Wu), `| 〇 ||`. These weren't "zero" but rather to clarify a vacant position.

Tracing the [parallel evolution of the numeral zero is pretty well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#History) and was a pragmatic thing.

---

The concept of "zero" as its own stand alone number has puzzled mathematicians and philosophers for a long time. To many, numbers were for counting and adding real things. Five sheep. Ten gold pieces. Two hundred acres. Numbers represented real things. These are the [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Saying "zero sheep" seemed weird. If you have no sheep just don't write down sheep on your list. How can nothing be something? How can you "have" no sheep? How can there even *be nothing*? In the classical view there was always *something*. There was always a medium to exist in, be it air, water, earth, or [aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_(classical_element)).

This is similar to a modern person wondering about infinity. Is infinity a real thing? Or just something mathematicians faff about with? But unlike infinity [which is not a number it's a concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elvOZm0d4H0), zero has come around to being accepted as a number. Infinity is not a number. You can't add, subtract, multiply, or divide infinities (not without [defining whole new number systems with new axioms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88)).

While weird things happen around zero, like dividing by zero ([which is not infinity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRRolKTlF6Q)), you can add, divide, multiply, and subtract zero. Including zero in your mathematical system makes many things easier.

The acceptance of zero as its own number is a bit more muddled. If you want to get into that, you might be interested in [*Zero: The Biography of a Dangerous Idea*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0xNvJqQEEvMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zero&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrurjXsN7cAhUrFjQIHX1LAzsQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=zero&f=false) and [*Finding Zero: A Mathematician's Odyssey to Uncover the Origins of Numbers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nAADBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=zero&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrurjXsN7cAhUrFjQIHX1LAzsQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=zero&f=false).

Comment: Nicely done. I was not expecting to see an answer better than mine.

Comment: I mostly like that, but have a slight problem with 'something', well "always something". I guess it's based on the "dangerous idea book", but Parmenides likes to object with *ex nihilo nihil fit.*

Comment: You discuss spaces between words in the context of the Chinese language, adding that reading was hard *back then*. But Chinese does not even have spaces between words today.

Answer (score 5):

The base-10 [Arabic number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals#Origins) you are using in your question **also** didn't exist back then. It couldn't have because, as you have noticed, the entire concept relies on having the concept of "0". The system was invented in India around 700 AD (not so coincidentally only about a generation after someone there discovered the concept of 0). A bit more than a century later it was being used in the Arab world, and a bit over a century after that in Europe.

In their previous written systems, of course there was a number between their 9 and their 11. For example, for [the Romans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) and people in their domains the sequence 9, 10, 11 would be written "IX, X, XI".

The only lasting effect this had on our calendar system is that there is no [year 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero). The Gregorian Calendar we use goes straight from 1 BC to 1 AD with no year in between them.

Comment: The shorthand of IV for IIII and IX for VIIII, etc.,  is a Medieval invention.

Comment: Note also how easily the *original* Roman system transcribes to and from an [abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus) - where they performed their calculations .

Comment: Don't have good sources, but have you reversed the order of invention for [place-notation and zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system#Main_numeral_systems), or do *I* misunderstand the language here?

Comment: @LangLangC - From the link: "The decimal Hindu–Arabic numeral system with zero was developed in India by around AD 700.The development was gradual, spanning several centuries, but the decisive step was probably provided by Brahmagupta's formulation of zero as a number in AD 628". I probably could have phrased it better though. Suggestions?

Comment: You wrote: "was invented around 700 AD (not so coincidentally only about a generation after someone there discovered the concept of 0)." I read that as ambiguously clashing with (my link) "Two Indian mathematicians are credited with developing it. Aryabhata of Kusumapura developed the place-value notation in the 5th century and a century later Brahmagupta introduced the symbol for zero."

Comment: @LangLangC - Place value notation is a wonderful discovery too. All of modern information theory would be impossible without it. Dude's name should be better known. It looks like my second sentence is the one that's really inconsistent with what you knew. I'll have to take some time at some point to look into how he did it without a 0 digit...

Answer (score 4):

You are [conflating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0) the *quantity* or [*number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) zero, denoting none, with the [*numeral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit) or symbol explicitly denoting the quantity of none, and represented in our [Arabic Numeral](http://arabic%20numerals) system by '*0*' but also named *zero*. The significance of the symbol '*0*' is its utility as a placeholder when performing complex calculations on paper.

Note that numeral systems prior to the introduction of a symbol Zero, such as [Roman Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), had no difficulty maintaining a Base 10 representation system, but simply used different symbols at each power of ten:

- I and V to represent one and five *units* respectively
- X and L to represent one and five *tens* respectively
- C and D to represent one and five *hundreds* respectively
- M to represent one *thousands*

Note that the Romans did not require a Zero placeholder for calculation as they performed calculations on an [abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus) rather than on paper. The inspiration for an explicit placeholder probably originates, and coincides, with additional representations for the [development of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_algebra).

The Ancient Babylonians also had no difficulty maintaining [extensive accounting records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_accounting#Early_development_of_accounting) without a placeholder for Zero by using a [Base 60 numeral system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_numerals)

The concept of *nothingness*, the *number zero*, is as old as numbers themselves. However the explicit representation of numerical zero, and specifically its use as a placeholder to simplify the representation of large numbers, is more recent. The [precise origins](https://www.livescience.com/27853-who-invented-zero.html) are debated, but it certainly appears in India and Middle East early in the Christian Era, as well as independently in the Mayan records about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use positional digit system you can calculate properly even without the zero numeral. The ancient Mesapotamians did their math in sexagesimal number system without use of zero symbols; the ancient Chinese did not use zero numerals when doing computations with counting rods or abacus, but originally use blank placeholders or none value settings.

Although later use of zero numerals undeniably facilitated the number system and expressions.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by directly addressing the question with regard to calendars and by including authoritative references for your assertions.